# Mysql : how to use variable in Mysql query column name

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have an sql query :

```
$variable_tablename;
$componentkhy1 = $Ns_Azuredb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tabkh WHERE TabkhSystem = '".$varInput_CalcSystemKh."';");

foreach ($componentkhy1 as $rs_componentkhy1)
{
    $khsysy1 = $rs_componentkhy1->table_name;
}
```

instead of the `table_name`, i would like to use the variable `$variable_tablename` is it possible to do so?

Thanks guys

Comment: Where is `table_name`? Do you mean `tabkh`?

Comment: $khsysy1 = $rs_componentkhy1->table_name;  on here instead of table_name(it should have been colum name so appologies ) i want to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the variable into the string

```
$variable_tablename = 'tabkh';
$componentkhy1 = $Ns_Azuredb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `$variable_tablename` WHERE TabkhSystem = '".$varInput_CalcSystemKh."';");
```

If the variable is coming from the user, make sure you check it against a whitelist to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, what i actually want to replace with a variable is on here:   $khsysy1 = $rs_componentkhy1->table_name; instead of table_name, the variable.  so on my case the table name is created dynamically, thats why

Comment: The properties of the object are column names, not table names.

Comment: Use a variable in place of the property name: `$rs_componentkhy1->$variable_tablename`

Comment: Thats how i tried but nothing happening. Also php editor shows that as error. Is there a standard format to use it?

Comment: It should work. Update the question with your actual code.

Comment: You keep calling this the table name, but it's a column name. Are you sure you understand the difference?

Comment: Hi mate, i have a strange issue here now, the variable which i'm assigning here is come from a js variable where i pass it to php $x3 = "<script>document.writeln(concatinx3);</script>"; so when i subsitutue $khsysy1 = $rs_componentkhy1->$x3; it doesnt bring anything, am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: so what im trying to do here is get a Javascript variable convert it to a php variable then assign it to the column name(appologies , yes it should have been column name)

Comment: when i replace $x3 = "ACTUAL COLUMN NAME" with an actual column name it works with js (php  converted)variable it doesn't

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, not the server. You can't get a JavaScript variable into a PHP variable like that.

Comment: The client needs to send the column name as a parameter when submitting the form, or use AJAX.

Comment: How would i do it if i want to use ajax mate?thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225623/how-to-send-variables-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: I get it, thanks mate, so if have to ajax send the var ;
$.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "name=" + value
    });  so for url: do i have to use the current page url , i mean same url where my mysql code is?

Comment: Use `data: {name: value}` so it will be encoded properly.

Comment: I get it, thanks mate, so if have to ajax send the var ; $.ajax({ url: "/form.php", type: "post", data: "name=" + value }); so for url: do i have to use the current page url , i mean same url where my mysql code is? –

Comment: Yes. Of course you'll probably need to redesign how it works so that it sends the response that AJAX needs, not the full HTML of the page.

Comment: You should read a good AJAX tutorial, I can't teach you this in comments.